# How can I create an Excel sheet view for user input in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I wanted to create a view that is the same as an Excel sheet of some rows and some columns in which user can give inputs and it should grow dynamically but some cell should be filled by program internally and should be read only. I am making an windows form application using C#. Is there any way to do it in C#?

Comment: You could probably get away with just using a DataGridView ?

Comment: I'd look into filling a table (not too familiar with the winforms controls) with textboxes that take up the entire cellspace. Setting the values/making it readonly should be trivial then.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools to aid you in doing this task.  Telerik and Infragistics are 2 of them.

http://www.telerik.com/

http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-07-30/create-excel-asp-net-grid

http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/infragistics-excel/

This article may be useful too.
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;304662